# Laravel - what's the difference between storeAs vs storePubliclyAs? Files are going to the same folder anyway

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-storage

I have Livewire component where user can upload product photo.
I want that photo to go to public folder, which is `/storage/app/public` by default (fresh Laravel installation).

```
/**
 * @var TemporaryUploadedFile
 */
public $photo;

public function updatedPhoto() {
    $path = $this->photo->storePublicly();
}
```

But the file goes directly to `/storage/app` instead of `/storage/app/public`. If I call `->store()` the result is exactly the same.

The documentation says: `->storePublicly()`: "Store the uploaded file on a filesystem disk with public visibility." but I really don't understand the difference.

Can somebody clear this out?